# DataTables' Autofill extension with input elements not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

### Context

I am using the [dataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin with the [AutoFill](https://datatables.net/extensions/autofill) extension. It basically allows you to copy a cell by pulling the cross (bottom-right of it) up or down the column. This works fine in my project.

---

### Problem

However, when I try to copy an input inside of a cell, it clears the selected inputs. Reading the docs, it seems that the older version of the plugin enables the copying of inputs inside cells, just by adding a small [script](http://legacy.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/AutoFill/inputs.html). From the [current doc](https://datatables.net/extensions/autofill/options), by looking at the `write` option, the behaviour I am looking for should be possible by default:

> This callback is the corollary of fnRead, providing a method to
>   customise how AutoFill writes a calculated fill value to a given cell.
>   By default AutoFill will set the value in an input or select element
>   in a cell if found, otherwise it will set the value as HTML.

The thing is, when an input has an initial value, the copying works. But when adding/editing the value, it copies the previous one. It tried to add the read and write function options, but they are never called (see fiddle).

---

### Code

Here's a [jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5tqq9oa/3/) reproducing exactly my issue:

1. Drag down row.1 col.1  to row.2 col.1 -> works
2. Edit value of row.1 col.1 and repeat step 1 -> goes back to previous value
3. Enter value in row.1 col.2 and drag it down -> resets the values without copying

It seems that the value attribute is never updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `read` and `write` callbacks to retrieve and set values of `<input>` elements.

Also it seems that AutoFill tries to increment values by default. I had to add `step` callback to override this behavior.

```
new $.fn.dataTable.AutoFill(table, {
    "columnDefs": [{
        "read": function (cell) {
            return $('input', cell).val();
        },
        "write": function (cell, val) {
            return $('input', cell).val(val);
        },
        "step": function ( cell, read, last, i, x, y ) {
           return last === undefined ? read : last;
        },        
        "targets": [0,1,2] // Use "_all" to target all columns
    }]
});
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w5tqq9oa/32/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for ... I'm not able to drag the cell... am I missing something?

Comment: @singhswat, example pulled the latest AutoFill extension which is not compatible with the code and DataTables library. I updated the example to use older AutoFill extension. This answer may need to be updated for the latest versions of the extensions.