# DataTables' Autofill extension - column disabling not working

Tags: datatables, autofill

I am using the Datatables plugin with the Autofill extension with input elements as outlined here: 
[DataTables' Autofill extension with input elements not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31291090/datatables-autofill-extension-with-input-elements-not-working).
This works well.  However, I am unable to disable the autofill for specific columns.  When I use the "enable": false option, and set it to specific columns, then the callbacks stop working.  Does anyone know if there is a way to disable certain columns for autofill, while still allowing the callbacks to function properly?  The following disables cols 1-4, but the read/write/step functions no longer copy edited input values:

```
    new $.fn.dataTable.AutoFill(table, {
        "columnDefs": [{
            "targets": [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],

            "read": function (cell) {
                return $('input', cell).val();
            },
            "write": function (cell, val) {
                return $('input', cell).val(val);
            },
            "step": function (cell, read, last, i, x, y) {
                return last === undefined ? read : last;
            },
            "enable": false, "targets": [1,2,3,4] //omitting this leaves all columns enabled.
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written it, you are defining the `targets` property twice in the same object. What you need to do is to give `columnDefs` another object pointing to the other targets. Like so:

```js
new $.fn.dataTable.AutoFill(table, {
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            read: function (cell) {
                return $('input', cell).val();
            },
            write: function (cell, val) {
                return $('input', cell).val(val);
            },
            step: function (cell, read, last, i, x, y) {
                return last === undefined ? read : last;
            }
        },
        {
            targets: [1,2,3,4],
            enable: false
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for but where would this function go... can you please share a pseudo code example